# Why isn't gcc recognizing my .c file even when I provide it as an argument?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I have `file1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    file2();

}
```

and `file2.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int file2() {
}
```

I'm trying to compile `file1` with `gcc -o file1 file1.c file2.c`, but I'm getting the error `implicit declaration of function 'file2' is invalid`.

Does anyone know what I could be missing here? `file1.c` and `file2.c` are both in the same folder.

Comment: `gcc -o file1 file1.c -include file2.c`. Don't actually do it...

Answer (score 2):

> *Does anyone know what I could be missing here?*

Each source file is treated separately when being compiled. Thus the compiler when taking care of `file.1.c` is unaware of what `file2()` might be and complains.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the function prototype `int file2(void);` in your `file1.c` or any included files, because each file is compiled separately and you need to till the compiler where he can find the function before you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the function declaration in you `file1.c` file also. Like so

```
#include <stdio.h>

int file2();

int main() {
    file2();
}
```

Comment: Make it a prototype: `int file2(void);` — that way the compiler can stop it being called incorrectly.